# purpose of returning hash iteration value

Tags: ruby, hash

In Ruby, if we have a hash called `my_hash` and we decide to `puts` the key and value, it seems we can use:

```
my_hash.each do |key, value|
  puts key, my_hash[key]
end
```

or

```
my_hash.each do |key, value|
  puts key, value
end
```

My question is why does `my_hash[key]` return the value? And what advantage (if any) is there to using that versus just `value`?

Comment: What made you think that way..Your second one is the obvious one,every body should use in such a case...

Comment: Regardless of whether you choose to accept my answer, remember to accept *an* answer on questions you ask, if one of them has provided you sufficiently with the solution, or the steps toward it.  Welcome to StackOverflow

Answer (score 1):

There is no advantage.

It will be slower, if your key is not a `:symbol`.

This is because the iterator has already done the lookup and assigned the value to the `value` variable.  If you look it up again, you're redoing that work.   A hash with an symbol for a key will have `O(1)` lookup, but other key types may occur in larger times.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I'm still unclear why 'my_hash[key]' returns the value?

Comment: @bananatron Why do you expect `my_hash[key]` shouldn't return any value ?

Comment: Because the key is labelled key and value is labelled value, without knowing exactly how it's working it seems reasonable that my_hash[key] would pull the KEY out of the hash, not the value.

Comment: @bananatron see the documentation then - http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D

Comment: @bananatron you have a fundamental misunderstanding of how Hashes work. Any basic Ruby tutorial should clear up your confusion.

Comment: @Max I understand now that the my_hash[key] is calling what the key is referencing (the value) and not the identifier called 'key.' Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

If you are seeking out something you use a key to get it. The idea of a key means you "already have the key". So why would you give a Hash something you have, and expect the same thing back, when you've already got it. The Hash would just look at you and wonder what this silly human is doing.

The purpose of a key is to open a door to the other side... that's why the key opens up the value beyond the door Hash.

It's like an index at a book store.  You find the book by it's index.  The index is the key, and the book is the value.